# Удалить строку физически, но оставить ссылку

Tags: sql, postgresql

Работаю в PostgreSQL

У меня есть две таблицы. Первый - это товар,а второй - ЧЕК. На нее ссылаюсь с помощью внешнего ключа (товара в таблице чек). Мне нужно удалить строку продукта (списать так сказать) из таблицы товар, но сохранить ссылку. Я хотел бы сделать так. Удалить ссылку физически с таблицы товар, но при этом дальше ссылаться таблица ЧЕК будет через "виртуальную таблицу" товара где будет дальше ссылка. Знаю, что можно создать поле с пометкой (удалено или нет), но хотел бы как написал.

Но я не могу понять, как это сделать... Может ли кто-нибудь сказать мне или показать, как это сделать?

Comment: под таблицей "товар" подразумевается справочник товаров или остатки товара/товарная партия?

Comment: @t0lik Остатки / товарная партия

Comment: @t0lik Думал как-то через триггер может это можно...

Comment: обычно товарная партия просто ставится закрытой, зачем ее удалять? Закрытая означает, что их нее нельзя набрать товар и у нее остаток 0. То, что вы называете "виртуальная таблица" тут больше похоже на историю партии. Нужна ли вам будет такая таблица потом с миллионами исторических записей? Может просто оставить ссылку на товар из справочника? Какую цель преследует хранение этой ссылки на удаленную партию?

Comment: @t0lik Я, хотел сделать так, чтобы данные не потерялись и в чеке хранилась информация какой товар использовался.  Возможно я запутался, но если это справочник товаров. Можно удалить из него поле, но чтобы ссылка из чека ссылалась уже на виртуальную таблицу с этим полем, а в настоящей уже не было ее, чтобы нельзя было вывести информацию пользователю товара, который не существует.

Comment: @t0lik как-то так я думаю.

Comment: Если полей не так много, то вариант скопировать их в позицию в чеке. Таким образом фиксируется состояние товара (название и прочие хар-ки) на момонт внесения его в чек.